# making specific regions of a buffer read-only

Tags: region, read-only-mode

I know it's possible to make a "portion" of a buffer read-only. As an effect, the whole line becomes uneditable. 
What I would like it to make a *specific region* uneditable, for exemple a rectangle region :

```
- item n°1 (uneditable) : "editable part 1"
- item n°2 (uneditable) : "editable part 2"
- and so on.
```

I'm pretty sure it's something customizable but I'm not well acquainted with elisp yet. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sentence in text is read only even though the buffer is not, how to fix this?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10091/sentence-in-text-is-read-only-even-though-the-buffer-is-not-how-to-fix-this)

Comment: Sorry, I'm aware of this post but it doesn't help (it makes the *whole* line uneditable).

Comment: The linked `set-region-read-only` function does what it says -- it makes the *region* read-only.  Use it on part of a line, and only that part of the line will be read-only.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you *very specifically* want this for rectangles, rather than for "specific regions".

You can combine https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10093/454 (which works on a region) with these rectangle commands:

```el
(defun set-rectangle-read-only (begin end)
  "`set-region-read-only' on a rectangle."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (apply-on-rectangle
     (lambda (startcol endcol)
       (set-region-read-only
        (progn (move-to-column startcol) (point))
        (progn (move-to-column endcol) (point))))
     begin end)))

(defun set-rectangle-writeable (begin end)
  "`set-region-writeable' on a rectangle."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (apply-on-rectangle
     (lambda (startcol endcol)
       (set-region-writeable
        (progn (move-to-column startcol) (point))
        (progn (move-to-column endcol) (point))))
     begin end)))
```